# Rails looking for a databases not specified by database.yml

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

I recently pulled some code and ran rspec.  The tests passed with no problem.  When I ran "rake db:migrate" and "rake db:prepare" however, I got an issue.

Now no rspec test passes, and every failure cites the same error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'app_test.admins' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `admins`
```

The thing is, that database name is not specified anywhere in the code.  In database.yml, 'app_test' is specified, with no '.admins' suffix.

Similarly, when I run rails server, I get the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'app_dev.admins' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `admins`
```

Only 'app_dev' is specified in yml.

The rake commands (db:migrate, db:test:prepare, db:create, db:drop, etc.) are all modifying the database.yml specified databases, it's just that Rails is looking for databases with the '.admins' suffix.  Where is this '.admins' suffix coming from and how can I remove it?

Comment: show your GemFile please

Comment: Gemfile - http://pastie.org/private/vszq8qmbgwukpo8f8qm6w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was as follows:

When I pulled the code, for whatever reason, the 'Admins' table disappeared from `db/schema.rb`.  This table cannot be restored via rake:db:migrate because the migration that created it uses `t.database_authenticatable`, which has been deprecated and no longer works with the Devise gem.  Because we're building on legacy code, we only run `rake db:migrate` on recently changed migrations, never from an empty database (for an empty database, we use `rake db:schema:load`).

Since the table was missing from `db/schema.rb` it would not be restored even if I used `rake db:schema:load`.  To fix the issue, I had to use `git reset` to revert to an old version of `db/schema.rb`.

To fix the Devise deprecation issue so that you can run all of your migrations, go here - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style

Answer (score 2):

app_test and app_dev are database names.

> it's just that Rails is looking for databases with the '.admins'
>   suffix.

Actually app_test.admins and app_dev.admins are tables that rails is looking for in the two databases. Couple of approaches that I would try:

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

or

```
rake db:schema:load
```

Answer (score 0):

Is rake db:prepare a valid command? Did you try rake db:create:all?

Comment: While `rake db:test:prepare` is valid, `rake db:prepare` is not.  `rake db:create:all` did not fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your `rails-settings-cached` is configured to use `admin` table? Do you remember typing `rails g settings admin`?

Check in your models for a admin.rb file, or for a model that derivates from `RailsSettings::CachedSettings`

Check your initializers for the same gem as well

Comment: I didn't type that command, but there is a model that derivates from `RailsSettings::CachedSettings`.  How can I change those settings to not use `.admins` tables?

Comment: Before I post the answer I need to know the name of the model

Comment: The model is called `settings`

Comment: That's not what I expected :) Then I guess I'm searching in the wrong direction. Sorry pal, good luck